# Mocking file input in React TestUtils

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, fs, reactjs-testutils

I have a component with the following render function:-

```
  render: function() {
   <input
    type="file"
    name: this.props.name,
    className={this.props.className}
    onChange={this.props.handleChange}
    accept={this.props.accept}/>
 }
```

State is managed by a container which uploads the file server-side using jquery AJAX call:

```
 getInitialState: function() {
   return {
     uploaded: false
  };
}

handleChange: function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var file = event.target.files[0];
if (!file) {
  return;
}

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
var self = this;

reader.onload = function(e) {
  var content = e.target.result;

 var a =  $.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/upload',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "input": content
    })
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("ERROR WHEN UPLOADING");
  });

 $.when(a).done(function() {
      self.setState({
      uploaded: true,
      });
  });

  } 
}
```

This works flawlessly with the server running.
However, I'd like to test without the need to invoke the server.
Here's the Mocha test I have written so far:

```
var React = require('react');
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');
var nock = require("nock");
var MyContainer = require('../containers/MyContainer');

describe('assert upload', function () {
  it("user action", function () {

    var api = nock("http://localhost:8080")
        .put("/upload", {input: "input"})
        .reply(200, {
        });

  var renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
          <MyContainer />
  );

  var fileInput = TestUtils.findAllInRenderedTree(renderedComponent,
           function(comp) { 
                           return(comp.type == "file");
                          });

 var fs = require('fs') ;
 var filename = "upload_test.txt"; 
 var fakeF = fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
 });

  TestUtils.Simulate.change(fileInput, { target: { value: fakeF } });

  assert(renderedComponent.state.uploaded === true);
  });
});
```

Getting this error:-

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$sn5kvzyx2f39pb9' of undefined
```

Comment: I can reproduce the same error simply doing `const node = document.getElementsByClassName("close"); TestUtils.Simulate.click(node);`, where I have a button with a `class="close"` on it, and it's the only element/object with that class, and those 2 lines are inside another button event handler I'm using.  Been looking around for a solution.  Using Chrome ver. 51.0.2704.103, React version 15.3.1.

Comment: I solved mine by doing `const node = document.getElementById("btnRequest")`, which is a button that opens (or closes) a modal window, instead of trying to go after the close button on the modal window, itself.  Instead of doing `var fileInput = TestUtils.findAllInRenderedTree...`, could you do something similar and do it one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a 'true' file? I think your issue is in how you're managing your 'fake' file, and your file input's change event. You can use the File Api to 'create' a dummy file, and then you just have to properly set your file input. It doesn't use `value`, but rather `files`.

```js
// similar example from KCD https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/93#issuecomment-392126991
const file = new File(['(⌐□_□)'], 'chucknorris.png', { type: 'image/png' });
TestUtils.Simulate.change(fileInput, { target: { files: [ file ] } });
```

If you actually needed the 'file' (upload_text.txt), then that could be more tricky. Node `fs.readFile` is async, and the data isn't available outside of the `callback`, plus you'd have to convert the `data` into an actual file object to give to the input.

```js
// rough pass at this, you'll have to play with it
import fs from 'fs';
const filename = 'upload_text.txt';
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  const file = new File(data, filename, { type: 'text/plain' });
  TestUtils.Simulate.change(fileInput, { target: { files: [ file ] } });
  // whatever comes next
});
```